# overwrite the createsuperuser.py

Tags: django, django-admin

How can i overwrite the createsuperuser.py script in django (1.3.1) ?

I'd like to add something in def handle in Command class after:

```
u = User.objects.create_superuser(username, email, password)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it would work for you to connect a [post_save](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#post-save) signal as such:

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

def superuser_post_save(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if instance.is_superuser:
        # do your stuff
post_save.connect(superuser_post_save, sender=User)
```

Of course that would also be executed if a superuser is created from the admin.